# mapping naked domain (www.example.com) to static website saved in s3

Tags: domain-name-system, web-server, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I am developing a web application. I recently purchased a domain from godaddy.com and am using  google apps for email, calendar, docs and other services as well.

Now I just need to show that "my site is under construction". I have a static page which is put on S3. Now I need to map "www.example.com" to that static page which is stored on s3. I am kinda of newbie/novice to this so kindly help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is article on Amazon Web Service blog [Host your static website on Amazon S3](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2011/02/host-your-static-website-on-amazon-s3.html)